# I can't summarize by multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarize my dataset by certain columns (Client, Year, LoS, and Country)

[image: This is the desired result]

But I don't get this when I use group_by, and then summarize, I get only partial summarization...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide data, code, current and expected output in a copy-pastable format not images. Use `dput(head(df,n))` for data.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, welcome, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In order to help you, a reproducible example is useful

Comment: In addition to reproducible example, please provide code you have tried, errors, warnings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(Client, Year, LoS, Country), function(x){colSums(x[,5:6]))}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? Please be more clear on what you need.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Client, Year, LoS, Country) %>%
  summarise_all("mean", na.rm = TRUE)
```